# Post on any facebook fan page as admin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am very new to Facebook and I have a task where i have to allow a user to log-in with his Facebook id, then select from list of pages on which he wants to post and then post the content. Can anyone please get me proper links to do this. I have done lots of research but I am unable to get this done in a proper flow. the content is always posted on the Facebook account and not on page. Please help.

Comment: it doesnt answer my question

Comment: It does – it tells you what kind of token you need. Apart from that, you did not really ask a question, you just told us that you can’t get it done.

Answer (score 1):

To post to a facebook page wall this post can help you out - http://programminghelp24.com/articles/jquery-javascript/how-to-post-to-facebook-page-wall-by-graph-api

you have to code so when user selects page, you assign page id in the above link's Graph api call.

Also if you want to post as admin of the page, then you have to add "manage_pages" permission in the last line -

> {scope:'publish_stream,manage_pages' });
>   but before adding that extra perm, verify that if the current user posting is the admin of the page. Use google.com to just search, its a common topic